# C#: Where do you call your own save method after pressing OK on a Settings Dialog for your program?

Tags: c#

Where would you place the SaveSettings method in your project when the user is done editing any settings on the Settings dialog in your program?

Should it be in the return like:

```
        using (frmSettings frmSettings = new frmSettings())
        {
            if (frmSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // clicked OK, should I call SaveSettings() here? 

            }
            else
            {
                // clicked cancel.
            }
        }
```

Or where should I place it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// clicked OK, should I call SaveSettings() here?
```

That seems like a good place. =)

EDIT: I suppose it depends on the framework of the application, but there's nothing wrong with putting it there.  It's a logical (by all definitions of logic) place to put it.

Comment: Thank you for the swift and very informative reply. Many many thank you's.

Comment: No problemo!  Do check the posts below though, as depending on the context it may be more appropriate to encapsulate this instead of directly calling (as Tom Moseley suggests), but that greatly depends on what you're doing, and only you'd know that for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Putting the save code in the calling form is, in my opinion, putting it in the incorrect place. Yes, it will work in this instance, but it means that the settings form is not reusable, and that any error in your save code will cause the settings form to dismount before you know of any errors.

Additionally, if you add a new setting, you need to make the changes in two source locations, once to add controls (and initialize them) in the settings form, and once to save the values, in the calling form.

I'd attach the code to the OK button of the Settings form. If any errors are experienced in the saving, you can inform the user while their changes are visible and repairable. The form will be able to be called from different locations, as needed, or moved with nothing more than moving the ShowDialog() call. Your handling of DialogResult.OK should be used to update the calling form as the changes in settings apply to it.

Comment: If the save is being implemented where the comment indicates, I agree with you, however I don't believe that is the case.  I think he's calling a save method.  To put the save code into the dialog makes it impossible to change settings without showing the dialog, so that's not very MVC.

Comment: I'm saving the settings into a Settings file in VSC#, and only calling out the Settings form in case of any editing. 

In this case, should I consider putting the SaveSettings() method in the frmSettings dialog to be all handled there? In that case do I leave empty: the form show dialog ok block?

Comment: Mitt - That's right. Put the SaveSettings() method in the frmSettings dialog. Your code need only call frmSettings.ShowDialog(). If you need to update the screen with any updated settings, use the DialogResult.OK block.

Comment: rmeador - Actually, I'd still attach the call to the Save method to the Accept button in frmSettings. I'd use a business tier to retrieve and set actual values, and put calls to these in the load and save methods of frmSettings. You could then use the business tier to get settings when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the Form Settings is doing.  If it just getting a user Okay or cancel then

```
// clicked OK, should I call SaveSettings() here?
```

is a good place.

However if you are getting setting information on the dialog form, then I would put the save logic in that form.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely don't think there's anything logically wrong with putting the save function where you have suggested. Alternatively, in at least some cases, I believe it would be more appropriate to call the function to save settings within the Settings form; but that depends a lot on the overall architecture of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If frmSettings form has the settings you need to save, I would store the settings from within that form -and in Isolated Storage or external XML file depending on your design.